# git init --bare permission denied on 16gb USB stick

Tags: windows-7, permissions, git, version-control

I am using GIT on a Windows 7 machine (64 bit) and have been learning how to use GIT to version control my files.

Now I want to be able to create a `--bare` repository on an external device (in this case a 16gb USB stick) but unfortunately when I try to create a `--bare` repository on it I get the following error:

```
f:/: Permission denied
```

I am using the GIT Bash program which is installed with GIT on Windows machines, so these are the commands I am typing in (I am also opening the program as administrator by holding ctrl + shift when I open it)

```
cd /f
git init --bare
f:/: Permission denied
```

However if I create a normal repository it works just fine:

```
cd /f
git init
Initialized empty repository in f:/.git/
```

Can anybody shed some light on why I can't create a `--bare` repository?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIX systems, when you try to create a directory that already exists, return a "directory already exists" error. Windows will return a "permission denied" error if you could not create the directory if it didn't exist, even if it in fact does already exist. This gets a lot of programmers in trouble when they port UNIX code to Windows.

When you try to create a bare repository as `f:\`, the first thing `git` does is creates the directory to store it. It's expecting that if the directory already exists, it will get a "directory already exists" error. However, `f:\` is a *drive* to Windows. Windows interprets this as the program attempting to create a *drive*, and it denies `git` permission to do that. Since `git` doesn't understand this Windows quirk, it thinks it has no permission to access the directory.

The solution is to create the repository in a sub-directory.

(And to those who write/maintain `git`: Trying to create a directory to make sure it exists and then aborting if you get an error is *wrong* behavior. If you are creating a directory just to make sure it exists and you fail -- for any reason -- you should then check to see if the directory exists. This has caused many bugs in many different programs (like [this one](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/432)) and, gosh darn it, you guys should know this by now.)

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that git did things that way (I have only just started using it). In any case, it is working now so thank you very much for your help.